# How to make A record URL forwarding to <ip:port>?

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, port, host, forwarding

I have created a virtual machine on my dedicated server and I have been forwarding a port 1080 to port 80 on that machine. So I can access my VM by simply typing dedicated_srv_ip:1080. I have a domain example.com which I want to point at the VM. I want to accomplish that without a need to type the example.com:1080 sequence. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in an A record type. Yet, what you could do is to create a redirection in your webserver at example.com to redirect to your other IP address. For Apache, this is a nice example where he goes through a proxy to hide the implementation of the subdomain: https://serverfault.com/questions/195611/how-do-i-redirect-subdomains-to-a-different-port-on-the-same-server